# Web scraping tables on college basketball stats

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am new to webscraping and working on a test project in which I am trying to scrape every table of data on the following website for this particular team. There should be 15 tables but when I run my code, it only seems to pull the first 6 of the 15. How do I go about getting the rest of the tables?

Here is the code:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)
iowa_stats<- read_html("https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/iowa/2021.html")

iowa_stats %>% html_table()
```

Edit: So I decided to dig a little bit deeper into the problem and see if I could get any more insights. So I decided to start with the first table that doesn't appear when you call the html_table command which is the 'Totals' Table. I did the following to follow the path of the html all the way down to the table to see if I could figure out what's wrong. To do so, I used the following code.

```r
iowa_stats %>% html_nodes("body") %>% html_nodes("div#wrap") %>% html_nodes("div#all_totals.table_wrapper")
```

This is as far as I can get prior to getting an error. At the next step, there should be the following: div#div_totals.table_container.is_setup in which the table is stored but if I were to add that to the above code, it doesn't exist. When I type the following, it doesn't exist as well.

```r
iowa_stats %>% html_nodes("body") %>% html_nodes("div#wrap") %>% html_nodes("div#all_totals.table_wrapper") %>% html_nodes("div")
```

Does someone who is better with html/css have any idea why this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this webpage is storing some of the tables as comments.  To solve this read and save the web page.  Remove the comment tags and then process normally.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

iowa_stats<- read_html("https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/iowa/2021.html")
#Only save and work with the body
body<-html_node(iowa_stats,"body")
write_xml(body, "temp.xml")

#Find and remove comments
lines<-readLines("temp.xml")
lines<-lines[-grep("<!--", lines)]
lines<-lines[-grep("-->", lines)]
writeLines(lines, "temp2.xml")

#Read the file back in and process normally
body<-read_html("temp2.xml")
html_nodes(body, "table") %>% html_table()
```